# Есть ли в каких-либо из SQL движков неявный join через точку для полей с reference, типа как в 1с?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Для примера, в 1С можно написать:

```
select
   t1.Номенклатура.Наименование
from
   Документ.Накладная.Товары as t1
```

И движок выполнит неявное соединение таблиц Товары и Номенклатура, и подтянет Наименование. Это разворачивается в запрос типа:

```
select
   t2.Наименование
from
   Документ.Накладная.Товары as t1
   left join
   Справочник.Номенклатура as t2
   on t1.Номенклатура = t2.Ссылка
```

Есть ли такая возможность в каком-либо другом SQL движке?

Comment: *Есть ли такая возможность в каком-либо другом SQL движке?* Напрямую - нет. Просто за невозможностью такой ситуации. По причине отсутствия "таблицы в таблице".

Comment: Как-то Вы невнятно выразились. Невозможность ситациии чего? Так же не понятно, что подразумевается под "таблица в таблице". Словно в программировании бывают прямые и кривые пути. Не соответствующие стандарту - да. Но у всех движков SQL кучка своих отклонений от стандарта.

Comment: В SQL есть три уровня объектов. Database.Table.Column. Во всех абсолютно реляционных СУБД. Некоторые имеют надстройки - схему, например... но это уже не объекты уровня хранения, а объекты уровня группировки и разделения доступа. Тогда как в 1С в вашем `Документ.Накладная.Товары` каждый уровень - это таблица. Т.е. таблица в таблице в таблице получается. Это от того, что 1С мыслит объектами, а не таблицами, на уровне встроенного в неё SQL-подобного языка запросов, и неявно добавляет условия связывания. На уровне СУБД это `FROM Документ JOIN Накладная JOIN Товары`.

Comment: `Документ.Накладная.Товары` - это название таблицы с точками. Типа namespace. В более коротком намспейсе `Документ.Накладная` то же есть таблица, но в приведенном примере она не участвует совсем.  В приведенном мной примере там две таблицы - таблица товаров документов которая соединяется с таблицей описывающей эти товары.

1с мыслит объектами, даже на уровне запросов. Но объект с точки зрения БД - это запись некоторой таблицы. И неявное конструирование JOIN вполне можно осуществляться, даже просто опираясь на описания ключей, как я упомянул, если ключ описывает соединение подходящих полей.

Comment: Можно даже попробовать самому сделать такой препроцессор запросов, и может когда-нибудь на это созрею. Но пока интересовался, а вдруг такое уже есть где-нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

для этого в sql-стандартах есть понятие View

выглядит это примерно так:

```
CREATE VIEW [Products Above Average Price] AS
SELECT ProductName, Price
FROM Products
WHERE Price > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products);
```

а потом пользуетесь этим как и желаете. смотрите в документации к своей RDBMS как это осуществить.

Comment: не, тут не про вью

Comment: да, это не про view

Comment: естественно это не то. что вы ожидали. а как без реляций-связок вы свяжете таблицы как в 1с? вы думаете сам движок базы данных это может делать? этого не будет.

Comment: Придумать как связать это не проблема. Например, как я упомянул, частные случаи механизма reference вполне могут это описывать: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html. Но вопрос не в том, как это можно сделать, а в том в каком движке SQL уже есть возможность имплицит-разворота.